# How to build a music player for Motorola L7 phone?

Tags: motorola, audio-player

Is it possible for me to build a simple music player for Motorola L7 phone? If yes, how do I do it? Are there any online resources that can help?

Answer (score 0):

The L7 uses a normal J2ME developement enviroment.

More info [here](http://developer.motorola.com/products/handsets-other/motoslvrl7/)